# Error in Miniconda Virtual Environment on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, miniconda

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu system from 20.04 to 22.04 and encountered an issue my project was running smoothly on Ubuntu 20.04, but after the upgrade, I'm facing the following error:

```rb
OSError: /home/ahmad/miniconda3/envs/python3.6/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/libgdal.so.30)
```

I have tried several solutions I found online, including installing build-essentials, Python development headers, and even creating a new virtual environment, but the issue persists.

Here are some key details:

- I'm using Miniconda to manage my Python environment.
- I have created a virtual environment with Python 3.6 for my Django project.
- I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions to resolve this issue and successfully install GDAL in my virtual environment on Ubuntu 22.04.